# select count dentro do select

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Com a consulta abaixo esta retornando os valores total de cada mês, porém eu preciso contar a quantidades de vezes que cada item possui em cada mês.

```
SELECT instancia,
    (SELECT COUNT(instancia) FROM urt WHERE MONTH(ura_data) = 04) AS abril,
    (SELECT COUNT(instancia) FROM urt WHERE MONTH(ura_data) = 05) AS maio,
    (SELECT COUNT(instancia) FROM urt WHERE MONTH(ura_data) = 06) AS junho
from urt
```

[image: imagem]

Comment: "Cada mês" será sempre Abril, Maio e Junho ou serão todos os meses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não precisa fazer múltiplas seleções para isso, basta fazer a seleção de todos os dados, agrupar por instância e somar os registros por mês:

```
SELECT
    instancia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ura_data) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Jan",
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ura_data) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Fev",
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ura_data) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Mar"
FROM urt
GROUP BY instancia;
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aNNfjc7AuwBzyFhr2r8wbj/1)</sup>

Como, no MySQL, o valor booleano é interpretado como 1 ou 0, podemos somar direto o resultado da comparação, sem o `case when`:

```
SELECT
    instancia,
    SUM(MONTH(ura_data) = 1) as "Jan",
    SUM(MONTH(ura_data) = 2) as "Fev",
    SUM(MONTH(ura_data) = 3) as "Mar"
FROM urt
GROUP BY instancia;
```

Simplificando um pouco a leitura da SQL.

Comment: Esta solução é mais eficiente do que utilizar subselects, para um volume maior de dados a diferença no tempo de execução se tornará perceptível.

Comment: Muito bom, menino Anderson

Comment: @Sorack Mestre em SQL desde que nasci xD

Comment: Show!!! muito bom

Answer (score 2):

Referencia a instancia do SELECT mais externo nos subselects:

```
SELECT instancia, 
    (SELECT COUNT(instancia) FROM urt WHERE MONTH(ura_data) = 04 AND a.instancia = instancia) AS abril, 
    (SELECT COUNT(instancia) FROM urt WHERE MONTH(ura_data) = 05 AND a.instancia = instancia) AS maio, 
    (SELECT COUNT(instancia) FROM urt WHERE MONTH(ura_data) = 06 AND a.instancia = instancia) AS junho 
FROM urt a
```

Comment: Ficou show de bola!! muito obrigado, só mais uma coisa, tem como ordenar a coluna de junho de maior para menor???

Comment: Sim, use: ORDER BY 4 ASC.